# Remove inequalities from set of rules

Tags: equation-solving, rule

I solved a set of equation and use reduce on the set of solutions. Changing the equal sign to arrows I get some set of rules but some of the entries are inequalities. E.g.

```
{\[ScriptA][2, 1] != 0, 
 0 -> \[ScriptA][2, 2] - Sqrt[\[ScriptA][2, 2]^2], \[ScriptA][4, 
   4] -> 1, \[ScriptA][4, 3] -> 
  0, \[ScriptA][3, 3] -> -1, \[ScriptA][1, 2] -> (
  1 - \[ScriptA][2, 2]^2)/\[ScriptA][2, 1], \[ScriptA][1, 
   1] -> -\[ScriptA][2, 2]}
```

How can I remove in a systematic way the first kind of entries ($ \cal a[2,1]\neq 0)$ for my rules? I tried Deletecase with several patterns but that does not seem to work.

Thanks!

Comment: `Select[{...}, #[[0]] == Rule &]`? `Cases[{...}, _Rule]`?

Comment: FullForm of `a != b` is `Unequal[a,b]`, so you should use `DeleteCases` with this head: `DeleteCases[{<your set of rules>},_Unequal]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DeleteCases[{\[ScriptA][2, 1] != 0, 
0 -> \[ScriptA][2, 2] - Sqrt[\[ScriptA][2, 2]^2], \[ScriptA][4,4] -> 1,
\[ScriptA][4,3] -> 0, \[ScriptA][3, 3] -> -1,
\[ScriptA][1, 2] -> (1 - \[ScriptA][2, 2]^2)/\[ScriptA][2, 1],
\[ScriptA][1, 1] -> -\[ScriptA][2, 2]},_Unequal]
```

gives

```
{0 -> \[ScriptA][2, 2] - Sqrt[\[ScriptA][2, 2]^2], \[ScriptA][4,4] -> 1,
\[ScriptA][4,3] -> 0, \[ScriptA][3, 3] -> -1,
\[ScriptA][1, 2] -> (1 - \[ScriptA][2, 2]^2)/\[ScriptA][2, 1],
\[ScriptA][1, 1] -> -\[ScriptA][2, 2]}
```